# Spring Boot YAML: set null property value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I'm having trouble setting `null` as a property value.

This is how the value is defined in YAML file:

```
my-property: null
```

This is how I inject it in code:

```
@Value("${my-property}")
private String myProperty;
```

For some reason, Spring keeps injecting an empty string ("") instead of `null`. Am I missing something or is this an error in Spring?

Comment: Thats simply because 'null' in YAML file undestood as 'null' string, not null value. To get what you want just remove value at all and then use null as default value in EL: @Value("${my-property:null}")

Answer (score 4):

You can't, but this is not because YAML. YAML supports null as per:

[Empty field in yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089496/empty-field-in-yaml)

This is because of a Spring processor class, which turns "null" values into empty strings, see here:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/19986

Answer (score 1):

Try to use instead of `$` use this `#`.
Or try this `@Value("${<my-property>}")`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar use case, and had to go through quite a bit of trial and error.

The following two-step solution worked for me

1. Don't define `my-property` in the YAML file. This way Spring cannot (annoyingly) inject a *stringified* value  like `""` or `"~"` or `"null"`, and will be forced to look for a default value.
2. Use `#{null}` as the default value. This is an SpEL expression that evaluates to `null`.

In your example, it will be

```
@Value("${my-property:#{null}}")
private String myProperty;
```

Be careful not to mess up with the curly brackets.