# Ebextensions not deployed to AWS Beanstalk when creating an Empty File

Tags: jenkins, github, yaml, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

I have this **.config file** inside the **.ebextensions directory** in my sourcecode for an app, which is supposed to install and configure FileBeat inside my AWS Beanstalk environment. The sourcecode is pushed from GitHub to the Beanstalk environment via a Jenkins job.

Previously, I had coded the .config to create one file inside the Beanstalk environment with the configurations to install FileBeat. That worked fine, the file got created. Now, I want to create another file(so 2 files in total), which is empty (that is to be filled with data later, not via the .ebextensions). However, after that change, the Jenkins job for the deployment keeps hanging and when it finally ends, I can see the latest version(with 2 files) has **not** been deployed to the Beanstalk. I cannot understand **if ebextensions does not allow empty files to be created** or **if my syntax is wrong**.

I have added a screenshot of my .config file.Note that the first file does not have any content and the second one has.
[image]

Comment: Why if you just use `content: ""`?

Comment: @Marcin Thanks! The file gets created, however, the content of the file is shown as "" when I use the cat command in the linux server command line. Would be better if the file does not have any content inside at all.

Comment: Can you try putting empty value as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089496/empty-field-in-yaml). For example, `content: ~`

Comment: @Marcin Thanks, I tried that too. But still the same issue. When I use ~, the ~ is written into the file. When I use ''(two single quotes), '' is written into the file.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm that it's still not possible. Can't use `~` or `''` or `""` or blank content with or without the pipe modifier