# constructing object with key value and value accepting space in js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I might be wrong , but curious to know whether can i construct an object with key value pair, with value accepting space only

Somehow after parsing i need to get as

```
properties:
    name:
    value:       //accepting space



let property = { name: {'value':} }; //currently its giving me error like expression expected
```

I need to give something like this , is it possible in js or in react
Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean by `with value accepting space only`. Because you can do `let property = { name: {'value': ' ' } };` this.

Comment: @TheViralGriffin no i am not looking for empty string. as i said  i was looking for something like ```let property = { name: {'value':    } } ```

Comment: Then you can do empty string with ‘’

Comment: This is very much an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), from your comment on the answer it looks like you are actually trying to produce `YAML` with an empty property, which is a differenent question altogether (and a duplicate [Empty field in yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089496/empty-field-in-yaml))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create objects with undefined or null values, like this:

```
let property = {
  name: undefined,
  value: undefined
}

let null_property = {
  name: null,
  value: null
}
```

which is the closest you can get to 'empty space' in Javascript, if you mean what I think you mean.

You can't, however, not assign anything at all in your syntax because Javascript requires that something be assigned to every single variable. You can test this by noting that:

```
let thing;
```

and

```
let thing = undefined;
```

are the EXACT same line of code from your computer's perspective. The first is simply a convenient shorthand way to write the second.

Comment: i understood , in both cases , it will print either undefined or null , but i want is just an empty space with no value,  so what i was doing was converting the same to YAML and here they are expecting something with no value , not even empty string

Comment: Yup makes sense. In that case, `null` is probably what you're looking for, since the names are defined but simply have no value.

Comment: if i gave null , it will printing null as value , which is not expecting . I am looking for something like ```properties:
    name:
    value: ```

Comment: `key:     anotherKey:    ` will always be invalid Javascript, and also invalid JSON for that matter. Who is the 'they' you are referring to when you say they are expecting something with no value?